# KnockoutJS validation combining two observables?

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I have the following UI:

[image: ui of form]

We have a restriction on the income bound to its frequency. For example, if monthly is selected, then the maximum the user can input is `999999.99`, however, **if fortnightly is selected**, then the maximum that the user can input is `499999.99`

How do I achieve this with KnockoutJS and its Validation library ([Knockout-Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules))?

Right now, I have the following:

```
self.validate = ko.validatedObservable([
  self.usualTakeHomePayAmount.extend({
    min: {
      params: 0,
      message: minCurrencyAmountErrorMessage.toString()
    },
    max: {
      params: 999999.99,
      message: maxCurrencyAmountErrorMessage.toString()
    }
  })]);
```

But obviously that doesn't take into account the frequency field (titled How Often in the screenshot).

How do I achieve the validation required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a computed that returns the max amount depending on the selected frequency and then use that.

```
self.maxValue = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    switch(self.selectedFrequency())
        case "fortnightly":
            return 499999.99
        case "monthly":
            return 999999.99
        default:
            return 999999.99
});
```

Then use this computed value where you need to reference the max value:

```
self.validate = ko.validatedObservable([
    self.usualTakeHomePayAmount.extend({
        min: {
            params: 0,
            message: minCurrencyAmountErrorMessage.toString()
        },
        max: {
            params: self.maxValue(),
            message: maxCurrencyAmountErrorMessage.toString()
        }
})]);
```

I'm assuming here that you have the frequency in an observable named selectedFrequency. I've not tested any of this but hopefully it gives an idea of an approach you could take.

Comment: This seems like a nice idea, but it doesn't work. Say you're on Monthly, and you type `999999.99`, but then you change from *Monthly* to *Fortnightly*, the validation isn't triggered again to tell you that now it is invalid!

Comment: Your idea gave me an idea to get this fixed. I created a function where I pass it the frequency and it would returned the max value.